# How to redirect back to Listing page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got some pages going on. Each page shows Listings of items that users wish to sell, along with their prices and descriptions. At the bottom of the page is a link for creating a new listing.

What I want to do is have the back button return the user to the page they created he listing on -- NOT the index of all listings.

I can't just change the back button to

```
link_to 'Back', pages_universityofconnecticut_path
```

because it will link to the University of Connecticut even when used on Harvard's page. I hope that makes sense. How do I go about doing this?

I have used this line in my view to display only the listings where the school matches the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the solution of your problem, an excellent way by ryan

http://railscasts.com/episodes/131-going-back